# jQuery Image Sequence in Sticky Div

Tags: jquery, animation, sticky

I need some help in regards to images appearing in a sequence within a sticky div.

For example, as you scroll down the page a div will stick to the top and stay until I reach a certain point. Between the time it sticks and reaches the end point I need images to appear 1 by 1 with the first image appearing straight away and the last appearing as you reach the end point. It needs to follow the sequence so if the user scrolls back up it will 'rewind'.

I have a working in progress jsFiddle. Any help would be much appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/tebrown/avevLepz/3/

```
<div class="containers">
<section class="green"></section>
<div class="rowstick stickem-container">
    <div class="content1500">
        <div class="aside stickem">
            <div id="col1">Image 1</div>
            <div id="col2">Image 2</div>
            <div id="col3">Image 3</div>
            <div id="col1">Image 4</div>
            <div id="col2">Image 5</div>
            <div id="col3">Image 6</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<section class="blue"></section>
<section class="red"></section>
</div>
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I correctly interpreted what you were requesting, I think this should more or less give you what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/6fezb6wL/

I reformatted your mark-up so that there is now a container for each sticky image. I also changed up a lot of your CSS, but tried to add explanatory comments.

The short of it: I basically have them on `display: none` until they get to the right spot, at which point I "turn them on" and the previous one disappears behind it.  The overflow / 0-height hack is to prevent the images from moving up after they hit the bottom of their container.  I'm assuming that was part of the desired effect.

Here is another variation: http://jsfiddle.net/6fezb6wL/1/